# Using PXDatabase to Delete Records with Null Fields

Tags: acumatica

What is the proper way to use PXDATABASE to delete records in a table that specifically contain nulls?

Answer (score 3):

I’ll show the wrong way and the right way to work with NULLs using PXDatabase method.

This is an example of the wrong way.

```
PXDatabase.Delete<CWPAYINT>(
            new PXDataFieldRestrict<CWPAYINT.linePmtAmt>(PXDbType.Decimal, 0),
            new PXDataFieldRestrict<CWPAYINT.status>(PXDbType.VarChar, null)
        );
```

This will produce the following SQL script, which is not what we want:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM CWPAYINT WHERE [linePmtAmt] = @P0 AND [status] = @P1 AND CompanyID = 2',N'@P0 decimal(1,0),@P1 varchar(8000)',@P0=0,@P1=NULL
```

This is the proper way to address NULLs:

```
PXDatabase.Delete<CWPAYINT>(
            new PXDataFieldRestrict("linePmtAmt", 0),
            new PXDataFieldRestrict("status", PXDbType.VarChar, 1, null, PXComp.ISNULL)
```

);

This is the desired SQL script:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM CWPAYINT WHERE [linePmtAmt] = @P0 AND [status] IS NULL AND CompanyID = 2',N'@P0 int',@P0=0
```